Frontend hosting appended before BE call
I'm working on a project and used angular as frontend tech and .NET core in backend.
I have hosted the frontend in firebase ( https://myui.web.app ) and deployed backend in azure (https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/api/blogpost). The backend is working fine as hitting the endpoint is giving data, while calling the API with updated(azure hosted) service URL I'm getting the data.
But, while I'm calling from browser (after deployed frontend in firebase), frontend URL appended before backend URL(like the following)
TargetCall: https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/api/blogpost
But Calling: https://myui.web.app/myservice.azurewebsites.net/api/blogpost

In angular application, service consumed as follows:
getAllBlogPosts(): Observable<BlogPost[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<BlogPost[]>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/blogpost`);
}

apiBaseUrl has been set to azure URL.
By changing domain name, it doesn't help. The changed domain appeared in that position.
NB: While developing(targeted to the backend localhost server) it didn't occur and also cors has been allowed in azure app services for those domains.
Need solution for this problem (need to call target API from frontend app)

your apiBaseUrl=myservice.azurewebsites.net, but it should be https://myservice.azurewebsites.net. should work with the correct value
